# PHP reformat date before POST

Tags: php, mysql, date, post

while posting a date from a PHP form, I must enter it as YYYY-MM-DD to be accepted. is there a way I can reformat the date as it POSTS so people can enter it as DD-MM-YYYY?

```
. date("M d, Y", strtotime($_POST['dob']));
```

.. or something?

Answer (score 1):

It's running fine

```
<?php
echo date("M d, Y", strtotime('12-06-1982'));
?>
```

output

```
Jun 12, 1982
```

**UPDATE WITH EXAMPLE**

HTML

```
<form action="date.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="dob"/> <input type="submit" name="submitDate" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

date.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submitDate']){
echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($_POST['dob']));
}
?>
```

This will return the date in that format that you want. Simple!

Comment: yea for ECHO, but is it the same setup for $_POST?

Comment: Even this work : echo date("M d, Y", strtotime('2011-07-24 00:00:00'));

Comment: now the dates are posted as "12-31-1969" ?? when I enter todays date

Comment: @Warface let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1789/discussion-between-whiteb0x-and-warface)