# How to convert yyyymm to mmyyyy in php

Tags: php

I have this date (year and month) `201511` and I need to show in this format: `112015` (month and year).

I've tried this: `date('m/Y', strtotime($date))`, but does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php). This question has been answered with very good and definitive answers at least 50 times by now. With all due respect, but do some research before asking questions like these.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP reformat date before POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811323/php-reformat-date-before-post)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35473547/2943403

Comment: @michail_w that is a poor/unsuitable dupe link.  Please be more careful.

Comment: Please accept my appologies, but I tried using these solutions and my date does not have day and these solutions does not working for me

Comment: @user115812: Don't be.  You have given links. Go through that links and make some efforts. You will get an answer. :)

Comment: Ok, I will delete this post and once again accept my appologies

Comment: Is there a good reason to not use a simple string manipulation? (Non-date function)

Comment: Your solution doesn't work because `201511` is not a format `strtotime` knows.

Comment: what exactly do you want the answer to be ?

Comment: @dean the question states that month and date must be in opposite positions.  Ignore the slash in the coding attempt.

Comment: @mickmackusa i gave that answer and i was flagged, so i was puzzled.

Comment: @dean your deleted answer was useless.  It was processing today's date.  That is not the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to read in the format you have and do that properly. `date('m/Y')` is not the format you feed into that function.

Read
http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php

or http://php.net/manual/function.date.php if you really have to use `date()`.

> m and n | Numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros    | 01 through 12 or 1 through 12
>
> Y |   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits   | Examples: 1999 or 2003

```
$dateStringOldFormat = '201511';
$dateStringNewFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', $dateStringOldFormat)->format('mY');
```

Comment: Please make sure you are linking to the English php.net, simply as this is English StackOverflow and there are other languages available for those who do not seak English :)

Comment: ah sorry it always redirects to the german page as it is my locale...I'll correct it

Comment: you can also use a link without the language part http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php and it will redirect to the locale of the user

Answer (score 0):

If this were me, I would just use some string tools to get the values.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/1LMVj

```
$d = 201511;

$year = substr($d,0,4);
$month = substr($d,-2);

$reverse = $month.$year;
echo $reverse;
// 112015
```

Comment: Apologies it's a '.' in php for string concat - been a while.

Comment: @steros prob right :) - hence me upvoting your answer!

Comment: It's a good idea to test your code _before_ posting.  I recommend https://3v4l.org  this way you can see that you don't need to concat an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

If you have Full Date. Conversion is simple.
otherwise in this Format you can use  this method.

```
echo dateFormat('201511'); // Your Format


function dateFormat($input){
$date=substr($input, 0,4).'/'.substr($input, 4,5).'/13'; // add extra date grater than 12
return date('mY',strtotime($date));// convert and return
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If you are going to use `substr()` twice, why bother with `str_to_time()` and `date`?